# Spring Rest Service Return Type

Tags: ajax, rest, spring-mvc

I have a rest service in spring which can return a string or a json. For this in my js code while sending the ajax request, i have specified datatype as "*". I wanted to know how can i handle this in spring service

Answer (score 0):

All `produces` type are available in `org.springframework.http.MediaType` and for your requirement you can pass `*/*`.
Constant for that is `MediaType.ALL_VALUE` in java code.

But if you know that your service always return JSON then I prefer to use `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` instead of `MediaType.ALL_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

you can add attribute " produces" on your RequestMapping annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/yourPath", method = GET,
    produces = { "application/json", "application/xml",....all what you want as type})
```